# How to write a simple XML file

Tags: xml

Grandfather (GF) > Father > Children

Grandfather (GF) : has n number of children which denoted as father (F)

Father (F) : Father has n number of Children and also has an attribute father-name

Children : children has attribute child-name

Please correct me, if i'm wrong

```
<GF>
  <father>
     <father-name> f1
             <child-name> f1c1 </child-name>
             <child-name> f1c2 </child-name> 
     </father-name>
     <father-name> f2 
              <child-name> f2c1 </child-name> 
              <child-name> f2c2 </child-name>
              <child-name> f2c3 </child-name>
      </father-name>
      <father-name> f3
               <child-name> f3c1 </child-name>
      </father-name>
   <father>
</GF>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the the correct xml for your description

```
<GF>
     <father fName="f1">
             <child child-name="f1c1" />
             <child child-name="f1c2" />
     </father>
     <father fName="f2">
              <child child-name="f2c1" />
              <child child-name="f2c2" />
              <child child-name="f2c3" />
      </father>
      <father fName="f3">
               <child child-name="f3c1" />
      </father>
</GF>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much.  <child child-name="f1c1" />  is equals to <child>  <child-name> "f1c1" </child-name> </child>

Comment: @user744587: Yeah, at some point it does. But then child-name is not an attribute - it is a subnode of <child>. And that's not what you were looking for.